URL Rewrite rule to redirect http: to https: is not working - IIS 10 - Asp.Net Framework 4.8 - web forms - aspx
Using the URL Rewrite module in IIS 10 on a windows server 2022.
The rule to redirect http: to https: is not taking any effect (not working) Please read below...
Update: 06/06/2024
Here is what my rule look like.
Note: And the result does not redirect to https: Please read on...
Note: the rule is defined in the web.config file of the WebAppDemo web application here: inetpub/wwwroot/WebAppDemo/web.config file
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WebAppDemoHttpsRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/WebAppDemo(/.*)?$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}:9443{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

This does not redirect a http: request to https:
I am not sure what i am missing.
I recycled the App Pool for the "Default Web Site" -> WebAppDemo. Must the "Default Web Site" be restarted in order for the rule to take effect? I probably don't want to do this...
here is what my setup look like.
Default Web Site 
    WebAppDemo
    Binding:
        http:80
    url:http://my-host-name.myorg.com/WebAppDemo/Default.aspx           
    
New Web Site
    WebAppDemo
    Binding:
        https:9443(custom port)
        hostName:my-host-name.myorg.com
        port:9443
        Server Name Identifier (Checkbox checked)   
    url:https://my-host-name.myorg.com:9443/WebAppDemo/Default.aspx
    
Note: in both sites, the "WebAppDemo" points to the same physical directory 
    
Open browser (chrome)
browse: http://my-host-name.myorg.com/WebAppDemo/Default.aspx
Result: Does not redirect to the https: site.


As @Joe Davis said there is no direct way to set the only one application which is under some website to https by using the binding but there is workaround you could try to achieve your requirement.

Set the site binding to the website as below(you can set hostname ip based on your requirement)


2)Then use iis url rewrite rule which can help you to redirect your specific application url to the https and other will be served with http only:
 <rule name="https redirect" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="appname(/.*)?$" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
             <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
     </rule>
     <rule name="http redirect" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
             <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/appname(/.*)?$" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
     </rule>


I have updated my question with the rule but when i browse the http site, it is not redirecting to the https site. Please take a look at the details i have provided in the Update: section in my question

@blogs4t first of all set the rule at the default site level not application level. set the hostname for the http hostName:my-host-name.myorg.com. rule:<rule name="https redirect" stopProcessing="true">          <match url="WebAppDemo(/.*)?$" />          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />          </conditions>          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />      </rule>

thanks for your reply. Is it a must to specify the hostName to the http: binding for the default web site? I am not sure the other applications running under default web site use the same host name as my application or a different hostName. this is one of the reasons i want to create a new website for my application and redirect requests to the new site & binding and not disturb the other applications under default web site. Please help if i misunderstood.

@blogs4t if your requirement is to host under the default web site then you can choose this way. and yes it is batter and recommended to set the hostname to the http binding so that it will help you to redirect site to the http to https with the hostname.

Assuming you are using IIS, the certificate is tied to the IP/Port binding, which is tied to the website; Default Web Site in your case.
If having a certificate on the site will break applications on the single IIS Site you're using, I would split the applications out to their own sites.
Just having the port and cert on the site doesn't force the site and subsequent apps to use the port and cert so, really, you should be fine.
